# How can obtain SpotifyLookUpAPI.lib as a Premium Spotify user?

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I know it's deprecated and all (or I think it is), but I just want to do some tinkering, and the source code I have requires this library.  According to the project's GitHub website (https://github.com/Equalify/Miniplayer), you have to ask for this library.

I'm a Premium Spotify user.

How can I get this library?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the author of the library says you have to ask him for it. So… ask him?

Answer (score 0):

You should already have received the library via mail.

When i githubbed the miniplayer project the library was still very much work in progress - and it still is - which is why i did not want to include it.

It would not be good for me to provide the public with a possibly buggy/crashing library, so i opted for the *"contact me to get it"* approach where there will be a direct line of communication between me and the people that has the library.

For anyone else, the contact info is on the github page and in the library header file.